# how to copy current date files or particular date files in linux using rsync command?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu

I new to linux, How to current date file copy from source folder to another location using by rsync command,

I Tried:

> rsync -avzhe ssh root@192.168.0.100:/var/www/ /home/backup/

Here i copied all files and second time i did copy this increamental file only here, But I need only date wise file copy from source folder, How can i get this file date wise?

I found by `find command using date wise,` But I need rsync command... How can i copy files date wise or current date, any one help ...

thanks advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can use an include filter to include filenames containing a date and exclude everything else. For example:

```
rsync --include='*20131029*' --exclude='*' -avz user@host:src dest
```

If you want to get files based on modification time, you can use `find` to generate a file list and then pass the list to `rsync`:

```
ssh user@host "find src -type f -mtime -1" > /tmp/filesToCopy
rsync --files-from=/tmp/filesToCopy -avz user@host:src dest
rm /tmp/filesToCopy
```

Comment: I  tried this but can't work this "rsync --include='*20131029*' --exclude='*' -avz user@host:src dest", I used "rsync --include='*20131030*' --exclude="*" -avz root@host:/var/www/ /home/var/www/... I need this format but it didn't work ...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to copy the file/folder date wise

```
cp -r source_file target_file_$(date +%F)
```

then you have to rsync the data

```
rsync -avzhe ssh root@192.168.0.100:/var/www/ /home/backup/
```